# Cherrypy - reuse modules and hide exposed paths

Tags: python, rest, cherrypy

I have developed two separate modules which ultimately yield an object which can be passed to cherrypy's quickstart function like `chp.quickstart(the_app_object, '/', some_config)`. The `dispatcher` I use in `some_config` is `chp.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()`

Now I need to develop a module which wraps both.
As I put a reference to each of the first two apps in the third one, I get to a situation like this:

```
import cherrypy    

@cherrypy.expose
class HandlerApp1(object):
    def POST(self):
        return "output_app_1"

#If mounted, HandlerApp1 may be accessed at hostname:port/path_app_1
class App1(object):
    path_app_1 = HandlerApp1()

############################################################

@cherrypy.expose
class HandlerApp2(object):
    def POST(self):
        return "output_app_2"

#If mounted, HandlerApp2 may be accessed at hostname:port/path_app_2
class App2(object):
    path_app_2 = HandlerApp2()

############################################################

#If mounted, HandlerApp1 may be accessed at hostname:port/wrapped_1/path_app_1
#and HandlerApp2 at hostname:port/wrapped_2/path_app_2
class App3(object):
    wrapped_1 = App1()
    wrapped_2 = App2()
```

What I would like to invoke **both POST methods in a single call**, having something like this (continues from above):

```
@cherrypy.expose
class HandlerApp3(object):
    app_1 = App1()
    app_2 = App2()

    def POST(self):
        return app_1.POST() + app_2.POST()

##If mounted, HandlerApp3 may be accessed at hostname:port/path_app_3
class App3(object):
    path_app_3 = HandlerApp3()
```

However, having App3 as in the second part, the **individual old applications may still be accessed** at `hostname:port/path_app_3/app_1` and `hostname:port/path_app_3/app_2`, which is what I would like to avoid.

As I understand, this is because the chosen dispatcher (`chp.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()`) maps url path segments to attributes of the application object along the application mount point (in this case `'/'`), and then invokes the attribute object method corresponding to the request method (GET, POST, etc.) if the object instance as an `exposed` attribute (which is set by `@cherrypy.expose`), which means a POST to `hostname:port/path_app_3/app_1` would effectively invoke `<base_app_object>.path_app_3.app_1.POST()`.

I was wondering if it could be possible to somehow **"unexpose" exposed methods down the hierarchy**.

Simply renaming attributes in the third app won't do, obviously. I am not sure whether using dictionaries or another collection would help, as it feels like some hack relying on the library not properly accessing nested collections instead of attributes (assuming this would be enough to disrupt the path matching process.

Comment: you can set `HandlerApp2.exposed = False` and so on.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I have done temporarily (I hope). As I maintain both `App1`, `App2` and `App3`, I guess I should pass them an argument in their `__init__()` method set the whole app exposed or not. Hopefully I won't have to integrate modules developed by third parties and not modeled in this fashion. It'd be nice if there were some ***unexpose*** decorator to counter `expose` decorators down the hierarchy though.

Comment: I don't see how that'd be more useful though.

Comment: Just as to allow a service (i.e. a module) to rely on pre-existing ones without risking to expose them.I am thinking of a scenario where the whole system is deployed on a single machine, with a single cherrypy instance, no IPC mechanism are being used, and the new service relies on some old one which must not be accessible from the outside (i.e. wants to access it as an attribute of its own, not access it remotely via e.g. an intranet). If the new one integrates an old service which includes a hierarchy of sub-services, it may be tricky for the new one to manually deactivate each of them.